# Use ngrok for RDP - security

Tags: security, rdp, ngrok

I use ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) at work to be able to access my computer from home (We also have a VPN but I get errors) using :

```
ngrok tcp 3389
```

It works perfectly, but I was wondering how secure it is. Do I risk compromising the security of the company?

Comment: Yes, and you are likely breaching multiple security policies. You should not be doing this, and your employer will likely not be happy if they find out. Also this is off topic for Stack Overflow I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 aspects of security here:

1. encryption of the traffic running over the ngrok TCP tunnel.
2. authenticating access to the ngrok TCP tunnel.

For encryption, a ngrok TCP tunnel forwards raw TCP and does not encrypt your application's packets.  One way to encrypt your traffic is to have your RDP server and client negotiate an encrypted connection (for example over TLS).

For authentication, ngrok provides [IP Whitelisting](https://ngrok.com/docs#whitelist) for ngrok TCP tunnels.